# Firebase: Result from getIdToken() results in Error: Argument of type 'Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: angular, firebase, observable

I get the following error when I try to pass the Authorized `IdToken` as a string when making HTTP requests to Firebase:

> Argument of type 'Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

#### Firebase Auth: getIdToken()

```
getFirebaseToken() {
  return this.angularFireAuth
  .auth.currentUser.getIdToken(true).then(idToken => {
    this.token = idToken;
    return idToken;
  }).catch(tokenerror => {
    console.log(tokenerror);
  });
}
```

#### Get Settings from Server using Firebase ID Token

```
getSettings() {
  let firebaseToken = this.authenticationService.getFirebaseToken();

  return this.http.get<SettingsModel>(API.DB_URL + API.userSettings,
  {
    params: new HttpParams().set('auth', firebaseToken),
  }
  ).subscribe(settings => {
    console.log(settings);
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase method [`getIdToken`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User.html#getidtoken) returns a `Promise<string>`.

In your function `getFirebaseToken()`, you cannot return the `idToken` directly from within the Promise `then` block.

### Option 1: Async/Await

```
async function getSettings() {
  const firebaseToken = await this.angularFireAuth.auth.currentUser.getIdToken(true);
  this.http.get<SettingsModel>(API.DB_URL + API.userSettings, {
    params: new HttpParams().set('auth', firebaseToken) }).subscribe(settings => {
      console.log(settings);
    }
  )
}
```

### Option 2: Chain function calls

```
function getSettings(): Observable<SettingsModel> {
  return this.angularFireAuth.auth.currentUser.getIdToken(true).then(idToken => {
    return retrieveSettingsFromDB(idToken);
  }).catch(tokenerror => {
    console.log(tokenerror);
  });
}

function retrieveSettingsFromDB(idToken: string) {
  return this.http.get<SettingsModel>(API.DB_URL + API.userSettings,
    { params: new HttpParams().set('auth', idToken) });
}

getSettings().subscribe(settings => {
  console.log(settings);
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Option 1 worked for me. I will have to study more about async functions!

Side note: I couldn't get your Option 2 working. I got an 'A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.' with the Observable<SettingModel>

Comment: @MattyO Updated line `return this.angularFireAuth.auth.currentUser.getIdToken(true).then(...` (The `return` was missing).